Latex full first name of author in bibtex-natbib
I'm writing my thesis and trying to change the bibtex outcome. Right now I'm using 
\usepackage[comma,authoryear,round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
Now, I like, that the References are ordered alphabetically, what I don't like about this scenario is, that the first name is not printed, just the initials.
Example:
Laitinen, A. and Särkelä, A. (2018). Four conceptions of social pathology.
European Journal of Social Theory, 22(1):80–102
Instead of 
Laitinen, Arto and Särkelä, Arvi (2018). Four conceptions of social pathology.
European Journal of Social Theory, 22(1):80–102
The function in the natbiger.bst file is:
FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 's :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr
      "{vv~}{ll}{, jj}{, f}" format.name$ 't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        {
          namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * t * }
            {
              numnames #2 >
                { "" * }
% WoB Vorher:   { "," * }
                'skip$
              if$
              t "others" =
                { " " * "et~al." * }
% WoB Vorher:   { " " * "et~al." emphasize * }
                { ", und " * t * }
% WoB Vorher:   { " and1 " * t * }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
        't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
}


Please share a full, compilable minimum working example of your attempt.

I already tried several solutions from former StackExchange questions, none of those worked.
I also would like to have the DOI in the References.

I changed the packages to :
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{doi}
\renewcommand{\doitext}{}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
And now the DOI is showing, but the first name is still missing.

In the string "{vv~}{ll}{, jj}{, f}", have you tried changing {, f} to {, ff}?

@Mico Yes, I already tried it, but it changed nothing.

After modifying the bst file, did you run a full recompile cycle: LaTeX, BibTex, and LaTeX twice more?
